# Why would OnShow not be called for a TForm?

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-7, tform

I'm working in a project in Delphi 7 and I'm not extremely intimate with the language or runtime. I'm attempting to debug an issue where a form is made visible and painted and such but for some reason the OnShow event is not called. In what case can this happen? Where exactly should I look?

Comment: Are you sure the `OnShow` is what you need, perhaps you're confusing it with `OnActivate`?

Comment: @ain yes. It needs to do some work when the form is displayed, not just when it gets focus

Answer (score 4):

The only explanation that makes sense to me is that the OnShow event is not correctly connected to your handler. Check in the Object Inspector or the .dfm form. If you are connecting in code, make sure you connect early enough.

Comment: +1. This is the most likely culprit.  Simply having a method named "OnShow" or whatever isn't enough; it has to be bound to the event somehow.

Comment: It's bound in the dfm (object inspector)

Comment: +1 there is no other clear answer than this. i experience this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more possibility when OnShow event is not called, when form is displayed with

```
ShowWindow(Form.Handle, SW_SHOW);
```

I saw such thing in the past during looking into some project, that's really a bad idea for Delphi.

Comment: So does that include SW_SHOW* (like NOACTIVE etc?)

Comment: Yes you can search for "SW_SHOW" string in the project to check this possibility.

Comment: I haven't found anything directly connected that looks like it could cause it in our project our the libraries we reference.. :(

Answer (score 1):

you should check here

Fist OnShow() must be decleared.

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject); // <--- IM HERE!
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

Secondly...

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject); <--- IM HERE!
begin
 //this time will trigger
end;
```

and the last thing, you should open the Dfm look for the FormShow Event

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 284
  ClientWidth = 418
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnShow = FormShow      <--- IM HERE! without this it will not trigger the OnFormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

if still doesn't work it might be referred to other function name OnShow = FormStart or wat ever function name.

Comment: All of that is the same. It's referencing the correct function name and the event is in the dfm

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do some things when the form is loaded and you want to be sure that all components are initialized you might use loaded

```
protected
   procedure Loaded; override;
```

It is called during form creation.

It has the additional benefit that the form pops up initialized without a slow building of the form as may happen with OnActivate.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem when the OnShow handler set using the object inspector was not called I found that another handler was assigned during program execution overwriting my settings, so you may also look for a possible assignment to OnShow in the code.